# frame distortion in python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, video

I download one 1080p 60fps video from youtube and get frames in it via cv2, just as follows. Some frames are of distortion. I wonder what the problems may be, bad video or something else?

```
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('XX.mp4')
success, image = vidcap.read()
```

[image]

Comment: mention under which os are u working beacuse different os decodes format of video in different styles
In Fedora: DIVX, XVID, MJPG, X264, WMV1, WMV2. (XVID is more preferable. MJPG results in high size video. X264 gives very small size video)
In Windows: DIVX (More to be tested and added)

Comment: My os is ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I find that there are some problems in the video.